# Kohana DB connection change from MySql to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, kohana-3.2

I built a project with kohana 3.2 and used mysql as a default driver, now i am thinking to change it to PDO, i just need to know if it will make any effect on my application, if yes where i should check/fix the possible issues.

Comment: Read the manual and get to grips with the usage of PDO prior to converting a working project to new API.. That way, you know what to expect

Comment: yea i checked it but didnt found any good info there, after searching i got some idea about PDO usage in kohana, but thats not fool proof so holding on it now :(